# DECLARE on spark sql

Tags: sql, apache-spark-sql, data-conversion

Can someone give an idea on how would i DECLARE on spark sql coz i am doing a conversion of script from sql to spark sql.

```
DECLARE @MINID INT
SELECT @MINID = ISNULL(MIN(ID),3) FROM SAMPLETABLE
```

Thank you!

I have tried something like SET but it did not worked out for me.

Comment: The short answer is, it doesn't support anything like that. A longer answer would depend on what you are actually trying to.

Comment: Hey Andrew. This is what im doing with that declare

CREATE TABLE #TEMPTABLE
SELECT @MINID+ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY ID) AS ID